# Create an index column for array of objects by group

Tags: javascript

I want to create my own function which takes an array of objects as an argument and the key(s) to group by, then creates a key value pair of indexes based on the specified grouping key(s).

For instance:

```
var iris = [
  {"Sepal_Length":1,"Sepal_Width":3.2, "Species":"setosa"},
{"Sepal_Length":1,"Sepal_Width":3.3, "Species":"viridis"},
{"Sepal_Length":1,"Sepal_Width":3.5, "Species":"virsicolor"},
{"Sepal_Length":2,"Sepal_Width":3.7, "Species":"setosa"},
{"Sepal_Length":1,"Sepal_Width":3.2, "Species":"viridis"},
{"Sepal_Length":2,"Sepal_Width":3.8, "Species":"virsicolor"}]
```

I'd like to create a function that will allow me to group by Species generating a new array with an index:

```
var iris = [
  {"Sepal_Length":1,"Sepal_Width":3.2,"Species":"setosa", "index":1},
{"Sepal_Length":1,"Sepal_Width":3.3,"Species":"viridis", "index":2},
{"Sepal_Length":1,"Sepal_Width":3.5,"Species":"virsicolor", "index":3},
{"Sepal_Length":2,"Sepal_Width":3.7,"Species":"setosa", "index":1},
{"Sepal_Length":1,"Sepal_Width":3.2,"Species":"viridis", "index": 2},
{"Sepal_Length":2,"Sepal_Width":3.8,"Species":"virsicolor", "index": 3}]
```

I've tried using `map` and `forEach` but I'm newer to JS and I'm floundering a bit. Any help appreciated, thank you so much!

Comment: Not a valid javascript object

Comment: Like @Aswin Kumar said, it's not a valid JS object, the reason is the 3,2, it should be 3.2

Sinc "," is the separator for object properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an object for the indices and increment a max value if no index is set for this group.

```js
var iris = [{ Sepal_Length: 1, Sepal_Width: 32, Species: "setosa" }, { Sepal_Length: 1, Sepal_Width: 32, Species: "viridis" }, { Sepal_Length: 1, Sepal_Width: 32, Species: "virsicolor" }, { Sepal_Length: 2, Sepal_Width: 32, Species: "setosa" }, { Sepal_Length: 1, Sepal_Width: 32, Species: "viridis" }, { Sepal_Length: 2, Sepal_Width: 32, Species: "virsicolor" }],
    indices = Object.create(null), 
    max = 0,
    result = iris.map(o => Object.assign(
        {},
        o,
        { index: indices[o.Species] = indices[o.Species] || ++max }
   ));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is awesome, I love that I can expand on this and create an indexing column based on multiple columns (ie `{ index: indices[o.Species + o.Sepal_Length] = indices[o.Species + o.Sepal_Length] || ++max }` THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `map` object which has each unique value as key and it's index as value. [Destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the `key` to get the value and [`rest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) of the properties seperately. If the `map` object already has the key, use it. Else, increment the index and add a new key to `map`.

```js
var iris = [{Sepal_Length:1,Sepal_Width:3.2,Species:"setosa"},{Sepal_Length:1,Sepal_Width:3.2,Species:"viridis"},{Sepal_Length:1,Sepal_Width:3.2,Species:"virsicolor"},{Sepal_Length:2,Sepal_Width:3.2,Species:"setosa"},{Sepal_Length:1,Sepal_Width:3.2,Species:"viridis"},{Sepal_Length:2,Sepal_Width:3.2,Species:"virsicolor"}];

function addIndex(array, key) {
  let map = {}, index = 0;
  
  return array.map(o => {
    const value = o[key];
    map[value] = map[value] || ++index;
    return { ...o, index: map[value] }
  })
}

console.log(addIndex(iris, 'Species'))
console.log(addIndex(iris, 'Sepal_Length'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you want to group by multiple keys, you can create a string which is a combination of values for those keys seperated by `|`.

```
keys.map(k => o[k]).join('|')
```

Now, `map` object will have each unique combination for the keys mentioned in the parameter. Here's a snippet:

```js
var iris = [{Sepal_Length:1,Sepal_Width:3.2,Species:"setosa"},{Sepal_Length:1,Sepal_Width:3.2,Species:"viridis"},{Sepal_Length:1,Sepal_Width:3.2,Species:"virsicolor"},{Sepal_Length:2,Sepal_Width:3.2,Species:"setosa"},{Sepal_Length:1,Sepal_Width:3.2,Species:"viridis"},{Sepal_Length:2,Sepal_Width:3.2,Species:"virsicolor"}];

function addIndex(array, keys) {
  let map = {}, index = 0;
  
  return array.map(o => {
    const partial = keys.map(k => o[k]).join('|');
    map[partial] = map[partial] || ++index;
    return { ...o, index: map[partial] }
  })
}

console.log(addIndex(iris, ['Species', 'Sepal_Length']))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you @adiga! Is it possible though to still include the Species or Sepal_Length key in the final array rather than overwrite that column with an index?

Comment: @MayaGans I have fixed that. Also added an option to send and array of keys instead of a single key.

Comment: @MayaGans please select an answer that you think answers the question best and [mark it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289255) by clicking on the grey checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object with all the groupIds and then -

```
const groupObj = {
    "setosa": "1",
    "viridis": "2",
    "virsicolor": "3",
};

iris.map((item) => {
    item['index'] = groupObj[item.Species];
});

console.log(iris);
```